# Wordpress function inside PHP variable

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I need to put a shortcode inside a php variable like this.

```
<?php
var Variable = "<div class='container-uppotential'>
                </div>
                <div class='container-historialdepagos'>
                </div>
                <?php echo do_shortcode('[mper_account_form]');?>
               ";

return Variable;
?>
```

But it doesn't work like that. Any idea how can I make this code work as it is in the example?

Comment: *as it is in the example*? What example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all you are in php, then your variables should start with the $ sign, then you save the html markup, in a variable, and output it, finally, after all the markup your insert your shortcode. (By the way you have a typo in the shorcode, is mepr not mper)

```
<?php
    $variable = "<div class='container-uppotential'>
                    </div>
                    <div class='container-historialdepagos'>
                    </div>";

    echo $variable;
    echo do_shortcode('[mepr_account_form]');
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP is executed before anything is sent to the browser. PHP is not executed in the browser, only by the server.

You're trying to emit PHP code in Javascript. Javascript is executed in the browser. By the time the Javascript is executed, the PHP execution is long over. The server never sees the PHP code.

Basically you can't emit PHP in Javascript and expect it to work. You can emit Javascript in PHP, because the PHP will be executed first, and the resulting javascript will be sent to the browser, where the javascript will then be executed.

Imagine running the microwave for a minute, then putting a glass of water in it. The water will not be heated, because you added the water after the water-heating process.

If I were you, I would make the do_shortcode() call and save the result in a PHP variable, then emit the contents of that variable into the Javascript. That way the PHP execution happens at the PHP execution stage.

Now, if you depend on the Javascript to set some state that the PHP function depends on, you're next bet would be to use something like AJAX, and write a standalone PHP servlet that takes the state information from the AJAX call, executes PHP to generate the desired output, then the Javascript displays the result in the AJAX component.

Comment: Could you show me how to proceed in my example? I mean how to store the echo and the place it in the correct place :(

Comment: Hard to do to without knowing how your code is structured. Where does your PHP live and where does your Javascript come from? 

Basically you need to do the PHP function ahead of time and send the results to the browser somehow.

Comment: He's not executing PHP in Javascript. He's using PHP to fill in a string that will then be executed using Javascript. The only problem I see is that he has newlines in the string, but Javascript doesn't allow that without escaping.

Comment: No, he gives us what is clearly Javascript code, with a string containing a PHP tag. I don't see any PHP code anywhere except within the Javascript string. Since there needs to be Javascript around to turn that string into page output, that means we're at the javascript step (i.e. the browser), and not the PHP step. No PHP interpreter is ever going to see that PHP tag to execute the function.

Comment: @KeithTyler only a clarification OP wants to emit PHP code inside PHP code not javascript code, well is a bit a typo or misconception because the code inside php tags is not php code ... well this is so weird. ...

Comment: Eh, this is confusing. I see the <?php now, but the "var" and lack of $ triggered my Javascript thinking. 

Still, though, the problem is emitting PHP to the browser, which cannot handle it.

Instead he would want to do `...</div>".do_shortcode('[mper_account_form]')."...`

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I see with your code is that Javascript doesn't allow strings to contain newlines, so you need to split it up if you want it on multiple lines.

```
var Variable = "<div class='container-uppotential'>" + 
                "</div>" +
                "<div class='container-historialdepagos'>" +
                "</div>" + 
                "<?php echo do_shortcode('[mper_account_form]');?>";

return Variable;
```

Comment: The code is fine, the problem is that the "echo" doesn't work :/